# use two .nextval in an insert statement

Tags: oracle10g

I'm using oracle database and facing a problem where two id_poduct.nextval is creating as error: `ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYSTEM.SYS_C004166) violated`

It is a primary key. To use all is a requirement. Can I use 2 .nextval in a statement?

```
insert all 
   into sale_product values (id_product.nextval, id.currval, 'hello', 123, 1) 
   into sale_product values (id_product.nextval, id.currval, 'hi', 123, 1) 
select * from dual;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
insert into sale_product
select id_product.nextval, id.currval, a, b, c
from
(
    select 'hello' a, 123 b, 1 c from dual union all
    select 'hi'    a, 123 b, 1 c from dual
);
```

This doesn't use the `insert all` syntax, but it works the same way if you are only inserting into the same table.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `id_product.NEXTVAL` in the `first` INSERT is the same as the `second` INSERT, hence you'll get the `unique constraint` violation. if you remove the constraint and perform the insert, you'll notice the duplicate values!

The only way is to perform two bulk INSERTS in sequence or to have two seperate sequences with a different range, the latter would require an awful lot of coding and checking.

```
create table temp(id  number ,id2 number);

insert all 
   into temp values (supplier_seq.nextval, supplier_seq.currval) 
   into temp values (supplier_seq.nextval, supplier_seq.currval) 
select * from dual;


    ID        ID2
---------- ----------
     2          2
     2          2
```

**Refrence**
The subquery of the multitable insert statement cannot use a sequence
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#i2080134